# Right align a matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a matrix that I'd like to reorder so that the rows start with the characters that designate the end of the row (in my example `"~~"`).  The easiest way of explaining what I'm after is that I'd like my matrix aligned right rather than left.

I can't think of an easy way of doing this, but assume there must be.

```
input = structure(list(V1 = c("Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home"), 
    V2 = c("Asia", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Asia"), V3 = c("Japan", 
    "Germany", "Washington", "France", "~~"), V4 = c("Tokyo", 
    "NRW", "~~", "Paris", "~~"), V5 = c("~~", "Dusseldorf", "~~", 
    "~~", "~~"), V6 = c("~~", "~~", "~~", "~~", "~~")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

This is my desired output:

```
output = structure(list(V1 = c("~~", "~~", "~~", "~~", "~~"), V2 = c("~~", 
    "Home", "~~", "~~", "~~"), V3 = c("Home", "Europe", "~~", "Home", 
    "~~"), V4 = c("Asia", "Germany", "Home", "Europe", "~~"), V5 = c("Japan", 
    "NRW", "Americas", "France", "Home"), V6 = c("Tokyo", "Dusseldorf", 
    "Washington", "Paris", "Asia")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach in `base`:

```r
as.data.frame(t(apply(input, 1, function(r) 
                                 append(r[r != "~~"], rep("~~", sum(grepl("~~", r))), 0))))

#>   V1   V2     V3      V4       V5         V6
#> 1 ~~   ~~   Home    Asia    Japan      Tokyo
#> 2 ~~ Home Europe Germany      NRW Dusseldorf
#> 3 ~~   ~~     ~~    Home Americas Washington
#> 4 ~~   ~~   Home  Europe   France      Paris
#> 5 ~~   ~~     ~~      ~~     Home       Asia
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation under my solution. If you are using `apply` I would suggest `data.frame(t(apply(input, 1, \(x)c(x[x=='~~'], x[x!='~~']))))`

Comment: @Onyambu oh yeah, right. I dunno why I thought of indexing once, but not for the second part. That is better. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

In base R:

```
read.table(text=sub("([^~]+)\\s+(~.*)", "\\2 \\1", do.call(paste, input)))

  V1   V2     V3      V4       V5         V6
1 ~~   ~~   Home    Asia    Japan      Tokyo
2 ~~ Home Europe Germany      NRW Dusseldorf
3 ~~   ~~     ~~    Home Americas Washington
4 ~~   ~~   Home  Europe   France      Paris
5 ~~   ~~     ~~      ~~     Home       Asia
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand the "\\2 \\1" part?

Comment: @HarpoonHarry see the regex in use: https://regex101.com/r/mt5LSJ/1. In *"short"*, `do.call` pastes all the columns into one string, then regex pattern finds the occurrences of `~~`. Use of `(...)` in the regex pattern is called grouping. Second group/set of parentheses will be `~~` and the first group is everything else. `\\2 \\1` swaps the position of those "groups" to put `~~` at the beginning (in regex101 grouping is defined by `$`). Finally, `read.table` reads the data as a space-delimtied text string and converts to a dataframe.